# WSO2 ESB Service Proxy not timing out as per configuration

Tags: wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

We are using latest version of WSO2 ESB(4.6.0).We are exploring on implementing Proxy Service to a web service. The details are as follows:

An Axis2 Webservice Custom service proxy is setup using WSO2. The configuration is as follows:
Proxy XML: This synapse configuration was generated using WSO2 UI.

```
 <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="StockQuoteProxy" transports="https,http" statistics="enable" trace="enable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target faultSequence="myFaultHandler">
      <inSequence>
         <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService">
            <timeout>
               <duration>3000</duration>
               <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
            </timeout>
            <suspendOnFailure>
               <errorCodes>101504,101505</errorCodes>
               <initialDuration>1000</initialDuration>
               <progressionFactor>2.0</progressionFactor>
               <maximumDuration>10000</maximumDuration>
            </suspendOnFailure>
            <markForSuspension>
               <errorCodes>101507,101508,101505,101506,101509,101500,101510,101001,101000,101503,101504,101501</errorCodes>
               <retriesBeforeSuspension>1</retriesBeforeSuspension>
               <retryDelay>1</retryDelay>
            </markForSuspension>
         </address>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <publishWSDL uri="http:// localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService?wsdl"/>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

Sequence myFaultHandler XML:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="myFaultHandler" trace="enable">
   <header name="To" action="remove"/>
   <property name="RESPONSE" value="true"/>
   <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" action="remove" scope="axis2"/>
   <log level="custom">
      <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="error-message" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
      <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="error-code" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"/>
      <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="error-detail" expression="get-property('ERROR_DETAIL')"/>
      <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="error-exception" expression="get-property('ERROR_EXCEPTION')"/>
   </log>
   <makefault version="soap12">
      <code xmlns:soap12Env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" value="soap12Env:Receiver"/>
      <reason value="Webservice is either down or currently not reachable."/>
      <node></node>
      <role></role>
   </makefault>
   <send/>
</sequence>
```

When the webservice is down, this configuration throws a soap fault as defined.

When the webservice is taking time to send the response back, as defined in the proxy XML configuration it should timeout after 3 sec:

```
       <timeout>
           <duration>3000</duration>
           <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
        </timeout>
```

Even after the timeout period the proxy is still waiting for the response instead of throwing the fault back.

On analysis of the log file, we tried by modifying the following parameters in the below mentioned properties file but still the thread was stuck waiting for the response.

```
**synapse.properties**  
synapse.global_timeout_interval=3000  
synapse.connection.read_timeout=3000  
synapse.connection.connect_timeout=3000  
synapse.timeout_handler_interval=3000  

**nhttp.properties**  
http.socket.timeout=5000
```

It eventually times out and throws socket exception.

As per the specification (http://wso2.com/library/articles/wso2-enterprise-service-bus-endpoint-error-handling) after the timeout happens the endpoint should go to Timeout state, but in this case the endpoint is still in Active state and it is neither faulting nor discarding message. Some times it throws an error code 504. But this action is not consistent.

Please let know the changes required for a given proxy service to timeout/discard message, if the final webservice is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using http transport from the axis2.xml (which locates at CARBON_HOME/repository/conf/axis2 directory), you can fix that by configuring the time out parameters in that particular transport sender by adding parameters. For example,

```
<parameter name="SO_TIMEOUT">3000</parameter>
<parameter name="CONNECTION_TIMEOUT">3000</parameter>
```

Regards,
Asanka Sanjeewa.